# Study convergence of $x_{n+1} = a\left(x_n + {1\over x_n}\right)$, for $x_1 = a$ and $a \in (0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

> Given a recurrence relation:
>   $$
> x_{n+1} = a\left(x_n + {1\over x_n}\right) \\
> x_1 = a\\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   Show that:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> a \ge 1 &\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =+\infty \tag1\\
> a \in (0, 1) &\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =\sqrt{\frac{a}{1-a}} \tag2\\
> \end{align*}
> $$

---

I think I've been able to prove case $(1)$ but faced difficulties in case $(2)$. Here is what i've done for $a\ge 1$. Suppose a limit exists, then it must equal to one of the fixed points:
$$
\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = L \implies L = aL + {a\over L}\\
\iff L = \frac{\pm \sqrt{4a(1-a)}}{2(a-1)} = \mp \sqrt{\frac{a}{1-a}}
$$
Since $x_n > 0$ the only possible finite limit is $L = \sqrt{\frac{a}{1-a}}$.

Consider the following expression:
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = a\left(x_n - {1\over x_n}\right) - x_n =\frac{x_n^2(a-1)+a}{x_n} > 0
$$

Therefore $x_n$ in monotonically increasing:
$$
x_{n+1} \ge x_n
$$

Also for $a\ge1$:
$$
L = \sqrt{\frac{a}{1-a}}\notin \Bbb R
$$

Thus by monotonicity of $x_n$ the only possible options left is:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = +\infty
$$

---

I've tried to apply a similar reasoning to $(2)$ but unfortunately it lead nowhere. The difficulty is also in the fact that the sequence is not necessarily monotone. Here are two [sandboxes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5nnlmotj1c) i've [been using](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fvqsvfbs4u) while solving the problem.

> How can I show that the sequence has a limit when $a\in(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already showed 
$$ x_{n+1}\ge x_n. \tag{1}$$
Note that, by the AM-GM inequality, one has
$$ x_{n+1}\ge 2a.$$
From
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=a(x_n-x_{n-1}+{1\over x_n} - {1\over x_{n-1}})=a(1-{1\over x_nx_{n-1}})(x_n-x_{n-1})\le a(1-\frac{1}{4a^2})(x_n-x_{n-1})$$
one has
$$ 1-\frac{1}{4a^2}\ge 0$$
or $a>\frac12$.
Define $r= a(1-\frac{1}{4a^2})$ and then $r\in(0,1)$. So
$$ x_n-x_{n-1}\le r^{n-1}(x_2-x_1)$$
$$ x_n=\sum_{k=2}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})+x_1\le\sum_{k=2}^nr^{k-1}(x_2-x_1)+x_1<\infty.$$
Namely ${x_n}$ is bounded. Now one can use the Bounded Monotonic Convergence Principle to get the limit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please elaborate on $1-{1\over 4a^2} \ge 0$. Here $a$ is a given initial condition and $a\in(0, 1)$, while you are restricting it to be $a > {1\over 2}$. Is it rigorous to make such assumptions? Would't that contradict the initial conditions on $a$? Also I'm trying to wrap my mind on the last part, you have stated that $x_n < \infty$ why would that mean the boundedness for $x_n$?

Comment: @roman, this because $x_{n+1}-x_n\ge0$ and $x_{n}-x_{n-1}\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = a (x + 1/x)$, and suppose $0 < a < 1$.  $L = \sqrt{a/(1-a)}$ is the only fixed point of $f$ in the positive reals, and it is an attractor since $|f'(L)| = |2a-1| < 1$.  Moreover, there are no $2$-cycles: 
$$ f(f(x))-x =  \frac{(a+ (a+1) x^2)(a + (a-1)x^2)}{x(x^2+1)}$$
The endpoints of the immediate basin of attraction of an attracting fixed point can only be singular points, $\pm \infty$, non-attracting fixed points, and members of a $2$-cycle.  Thus in this case the immediate basin of attraction must be $(0, \infty)$, i.e. the sequence $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ starting anywhere in $(0,\infty$ will always converge to $L$.

Comment: That you for the answer, unfortunately the concepts you've used are beyond my level of knowledge for now. But I would appreciate if you could point me to the literature required to grasp those concepts.